# Pusher Eloquent Event trigger returns false HTTP API Req Laravel 5.7

Tags: laravel, api, events, eloquent, pusher

I have two eloquent model events performed by an API (insert and update). I have tested these with Postman and they're working I am getting logs of the operations performed. I have removed the logs, since my goal is to trigger pusher events when one of these events are triggered. I have set up pusher installing it from the composer. I have updated the config files and env ,which I will show below, and I have made some triggers to the channel from the pusher dashboard.

I am using Ubuntu 18.04 with apache, laravel 5.7 and when attempting an HTTP request I noticed that $re = $pusher->trigger('api-channel', 'model.insert', array('message' => 'hello')); returns false. I have tried both commenting the encrypt line in the config and setting it to the false, updating the time via ntp as suggested on other posts but these don't resolve my issue. I have tried triggering the event both from the controller and from the eventserviceprovider boot function but the result is always the same.

This is my js

```
//event listener for document repo api
// Enable pusher logging - don't include this in production
Pusher.logToConsole = true;

var pusher = new Pusher('*****', {
   cluster: 'eu',
   forceTLS: true
});

var channel = pusher.subscribe('api-channel');



channel.bind('model.insert', function(document) {
   alert(JSON.stringify(document.message));
   console.log(document);

});
```

I have tested if the config are setup correctly by adding these lines of code in the BroadCastManager.php

```
var_dump($config['key']);
var_dump($config['secret']);
var_dump( $config['app_id']);
var_dump($config['options']);
exit;
```

And from the output I can tell that they are correct.
This is my code when attempting trigger from the controller

```
namespace App\Http\Controllers;

.
.
.
use Illuminate\Http\Request;
use Pusher\Pusher as Pusher;

.
.
.
            if ($model->save()) {


                $options = array(
                    'cluster' => 'eu',
                    'encrypted' => false
//                'host' => '127.0.0.1',
//                'port' => 6001,
//                'scheme' => 'http'
                );
                $pusher = new Pusher(
                    'key',
                    'secret',
                    'app-id',
                    $options
                );

//                dd($pusher->get_channels());




                $re = $pusher->trigger('api-channel', 'model.insert', array('message' => 'hello'));

                dd($re);

                return new ModelResource($model);
            }
```

I have also attempted creating a laravel event and listener and triggering that event in the controller after a model change has been performed. In that case I get this error:

```
    "message": "",
    "exception": "Illuminate\\Broadcasting\\BroadcastException",
    "file": "/home/usr/projects/tdv/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Broadcasting/Broadcasters/PusherBroadcaster.php",
    "line": 117,
    "trace": [
        {
            "file": "/home/usr/projects/tdv/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Broadcasting/BroadcastEvent.php",
            "line": 48,
            "function": "broadcast",
            "class": "Illuminate\\Broadcasting\\Broadcasters\\PusherBroadcaster",
            "type": "->"
```

This is my event class. It is registered in the event service provider.

```
namespace App\Events;

use App\ModelRepository;
use Illuminate\Broadcasting\Channel;
use Illuminate\Queue\SerializesModels;
use Illuminate\Broadcasting\PrivateChannel;
use Illuminate\Broadcasting\PresenceChannel;
use Illuminate\Foundation\Events\Dispatchable;
use Illuminate\Broadcasting\InteractsWithSockets;
use Illuminate\Contracts\Broadcasting\ShouldBroadcast;
use Log;

class ModelEvent implements ShouldBroadcast
{
    use Dispatchable, InteractsWithSockets, SerializesModels;


    public $modelRepository;

    /**
     * Create a new event instance.
     *
     * @return void
     */
    public function __construct(ModelRepository $modelRepository)
    {
        //
        $this->$modelRepository = $modelRepository;
        $this->broadcast();
    }



    /**
     * Get the channels the event should broadcast on.
     *
     * @return \Illuminate\Broadcasting\Channel|array
     */
    public function broadcastOn()
    {
        return new Channel('api-channel');
    }

    public function broadcast()
    {
        $options = array(
            'cluster' => 'eu',
            'host' => '127.0.0.1',
            'port' => 6001,
            'scheme' => 'http',
            'useTLS' => true
        );
        $pusher = new Pusher(
            '***',
            '***',
            '***',
            $options
        );

        return $pusher->trigger('api-channel', 'model.insert', array('data' => $this->modelRepository));

    }
}
```

and in this case this is how I trigger the event in the controller

```
event(new ModelEvent(new ModelRepository()));
```

Thanks in advance! :)